# problems with cross field custom validation in go

Tags: go, validation, reflection

I'm trying to learn golang custom validation but running into a lot of trouble.  Here's the code for what I've been attempting:

```
package main
import (
        "reflect"
        "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
        "fmt"
)
type TeamMember struct {
        Country string
        Age int
        DropShip bool `validate:"is_eligible"`
}
func CustomValidation(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
  /*
    if(DropShip == true) {
       httpresponse = curl https://3rd-party-api.com/?country=<Country>&age=<Age>
       return httpresponse.code == 200
    }
    return false
  */

  b := fl.Parent()
  fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))
  fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(b))
  c := reflect.ValueOf(b).Interface()
  fmt.Println(c.(TeamMember))
  fmt.Println("============")
  return true
}


func main() {
  var validate *validator.Validate
  validate = validator.New(validator.WithRequiredStructEnabled())
  _ = validate.RegisterValidation("is_eligible", CustomValidation)
  teammember := TeamMember{"Canada", 34, true}

  validate.Struct(teammember)
}
```

You can see the validation logic that I'm attempting in the code comments...If the `DropShip` field is true, then I need to submit the `Country` and `Age` to another API to see if this team member is eligible.

The problem is that I'm struggling with the `reflect` library to access the `Country` and `Age` fields in the `TeamMember` struct.  The `fmt.Println(c.(TeamMember))` line crashes my program.

Can someone give me an example of how to access the other TeamMember fields?  Or is my approach to validation in violation of the idiomatic way of validating in golang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's better to use a custom struct level validation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type TeamMember struct {
    Country  string
    Age      int
    DropShip bool
}

func TeamMemberStructLevelValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {
    teamMember := sl.Current().Interface().(TeamMember)

    if teamMember.DropShip {
        // submit the Country and Age to another API to see if this team member is eligible.
        if teamMember.Country == "Canada" && teamMember.Age == 34 {
            sl.ReportError(teamMember.Country, "country", "Country", "is_eligible", "")
            sl.ReportError(teamMember.Age, "age", "Age", "is_eligible", "")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    validate := validator.New(validator.WithRequiredStructEnabled())
    validate.RegisterStructValidation(TeamMemberStructLevelValidation, TeamMember{})

    teamMember := TeamMember{"Canada", 34, true}
    err := validate.Struct(teamMember)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
    // Output:
    //   Key: 'TeamMember.country' Error:Field validation for 'country' failed on the 'is_eligible' tag
    //   Key: 'TeamMember.age' Error:Field validation for 'age' failed on the 'is_eligible' tag
}
```

See also this example provided by the package: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v10.15.3/_examples/struct-level/main.go.